# Loading text from textfile (beginner here) java

Tags: java

This is a code snippet from an addressbook project. I want to load text from a textfile but I am stuck because the class that I created can't be converted to a string and don't know how to scan.

So how can I load in two strings for example String firstname and String familyname? (edit) I have edited so I added methods that were missing and classes.

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String firstname;
  String familyname;

  Person(int id, String firstname, String familyname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.familyname = familyname;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  public void setFamilyname(String familyname) {
    this.familyname = familyname;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return this.firstname;
  }

  public String getFamilyname() {
    return this.familyname;
  }
}

class AddressBook {
  ArrayList<Person> addresses = new ArrayList<Person>();

  int id = 0;

  AddressBook() {
    load();

  public void add(String firstName, String familyName) {
    Person person = new Person(++id, firstName, familyName);
    addresses.add(person);
  }

  public void load() {
    try {
      File file = new File("AddressBook.txt");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
      Person person;
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        person = scanner.nextLine();
        add(person.getFirstname(),person.getFamilyname());
      } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error in input/output");
    }
  }

  public void save() {
    try {
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("AddressBook.txt", "UTF-8");
      for (Person person: addresses) {
        writer.println(person.getFirstname()+" "+person.getFamilyname());
      }
      writer.close();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error in input/output");      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use string.split(" "). but the way your code is built, will never work. nextLine() returns a String, while you try to assign it to an instance of Person

Comment: you should add to the code snippet a template, how data is saved in the file `"AddressBook.txt"` so you would know how to split the different fields in each line... :(

Comment: There is no procedure `add` as well.. where are you adding the `Person` ???

Comment: you now have methods defined outside of a class. your add method tries to add persons to 'addresses', but there is no such variable.

Comment: that's a better code.. in the future, always include all your relevant code so that you could receive some help..

Comment: ok Thanks for the help!

Comment: where do you define `id` used in `add` procedure ?

Comment: `id` could be a global variable in the class `AddressBook`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet. Get the line from the file, split it using space and use.

```
public void load() {
        try {
            File file = new File("AddressBook.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            Person person;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] split = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                add(split[0], split[1]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in input/output");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might need to explain why you have done some update, why `person = scanner.nextLine()` doesn't compile. Why you `split`, ...